# Refactoring query to select lst of type

Tags: c#, linq, select

Although this method works as it should. I am fairly certain there is a way to do all of this in the query (i.e. return the list of type CreatorsDto). I've searched and searched and tried numerous ways but am getting nowhere.

This method pulls data from an xml file, the format of which is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Creators>
  <Creator name="name here" field="field here">
    <ImageUrl value="url here" />
    <SocialLinks>
      <Twitter value="www.twitter.com/twitter handle here" />
      <Facebook value="www.facebook.com/facebook handle here" />
      <Linkedin value="www.linkedin.com/linkedin handle here" />
      <Instagram value="www.instagram.com/insta handle here" />
    </SocialLinks>
  </Creator>
```

and the method

```
public List<CreatorsDto> BuildModelFromCreatorsXmlFile()
{
    var cvmList = new List<CreatorsDto>();
    var result = _doc.Descendants("Creator")
        .Where(a => (string) a.Attribute("name") != string.Empty)
        .Where(a => (string) a.Attribute("field") != string.Empty)
        .ToList();
    foreach (var creator in result)
    {
        var cvm = new CreatorsDto
        {
            CreatorField = creator.Attribute("field")?.Value,
            CreatorName = creator.Attribute("name")?.Value,
            CreatorHeadShotUrl = creator.Element("ImageUrl")?.Attribute("value")?.Value
        };
        var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        foreach (var link in creator.Element("SocialLinks") != null
                ? creator.Element("SocialLinks").Descendants()
                : null)
        {
            dict.Add(link.Name.ToString(),link.Attribute("value")?.Value);
        }
            cvm.SocialLinks = dict;
            cvmList.Add(cvm);
        }

     return cvmList;
}
```

I know after the last Where clause, I need a Select statement

```
.Where(a => (string) a.Attribute("field") != string.Empty)
.Select( new CreatorsDto
    {
       // everything I try in here is no good
    })
 .ToList();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Put `foreach` in a separated method which takes `<Creator>` element as argument and returns created instance if `CreatorDto`.

Comment: @Fabio...thank you, but that's not answering the question asked, which is how to do the whole operation within the query

Comment: If you want everything in the query, just copy block of `foreach` inside block of `Select` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want whole logic in "one" query, the it can look like code below:

```
document.Descendants("Creator")
        .Where(creator => string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)creator.Attribute("name")) == false)
        .Where(creator => string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)creator.Attribute("field")) == false)
        .Select(creator =>
        {
            return new CreatorDto
            {
                Name = creator.Attribute("name").Value,
                Field = creator.Attribute("field").Value,
                ImageUrl = creator.Element("ImageUrl")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
                SocialLinks = 
                    (creator.Element("SocialLinks") ?? new XElement("SocialLinks"))
                        .Elements()
                        .ToDictionary(link => link.Name.ToString(), 
                                      link => (string)link.Attribute("value"))
            };
        })
        .ToList();
```

Usage of null propagation after `Where` query is redundant inside `Select`.
For collection types can be good practice to never return a `null` - instead return an empty collection(Dictionary in this case) when there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a parameter to the `Select`lambda expression like you do with `Where` expressions. One possible solution is

```
public List<CreatorsDto> BuildModelFromCreatorsXmlFile()
{
    return _doc.Descendants("Creator")
        .Where(a => (string) a.Attribute("name") != string.Empty)
        .Where(a => (string) a.Attribute("field") != string.Empty)
        .Select(a => new CreatorsDto
            {
                CreatorField = a.Attribute("field")?.Value,
                CreatorName = a.Attribute("name")?.Value,
                CreatorHeadShotUrl = a.Element("ImageUrl")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
                SocialLinks = a.Element("SocialLinks")?.Descendants().ToDictionary(link => link.Name.ToString(), link => link.Attribute("value")?.Value)
            })  
        .ToList();
}
```